# How to change font of a selected text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox

> I want to change font of a selected text in richtextbox called **Notes**

I tried with this code but it doesn't work

```
Notes.SelectionFont = FontStyle.Italic;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;
Select a text then trigger

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selstart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            int sellength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart + richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = richTextBox1.Font;
            richTextBox1.Select(selstart, sellength);
        }
```